# When Export Kendo Grid the footerTemplate show html string?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have kendo grid with footerTemplate. I have export this grid as a excel successfully. But that exported excel footerTemplate show the html string.

**Sample Grid Column:**

```
           {
                field: "January",
                title: "January",
                aggregates: ["sum"],
                filterable: false,
                resourcename: "january",
                type: "currency",
                footerTemplate: function (data) {
                    return "<div style='white-space:initial;float:right'>" + kendo.toString(data.January.sum, "n0") + "</div>";
                }
            }
```

Image : [image]

**Question:**
     How to fix this html string issue??

Thanks.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure your `dataSource` contains the [`sum` `aggregate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.aggregates) function on the columns you wish to get the `sum` of:

```
dataSource: {
  data: [
    { item: "AB", january: 12.24 },
    { item: "CD", january: 22.23 }
  ],
  aggregate: [
    { field: "january", aggregate: "sum" }        
  ]
}
```

Then declare your [`footerTemplate`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.footerTemplate) on the column you wish to display the value:

```
columns: [
  { field: "item" },
  { field: "january",
    type: "currency",
    footerTemplate: "Sum: #: sum #"
  }
]
```

Full Dojo working example [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/iSeMA/2).

**EDIT** - to right-align content in the `footerTemplate`

Grid:

`footerTemplate: "<div style='text-align: right'>Sum: #: sum #</div>"`

Excel Export - Include the following [`excelExport`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-excelExport) function in your grid definition:

```
excelExport: function(e) {
    var rows = e.workbook.sheets[0].rows;

    for (var ri = 0; ri < rows.length; ri++) {
      var row = rows[ri];

      if (row.type == "group-footer" || row.type == "footer") {
        for (var ci = 0; ci < row.cells.length; ci++) {
          var cell = row.cells[ci];
          if (cell.value) {                
            cell.value = $(cell.value).text();
            // Set the alignment
            cell.hAlign = "right";
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[`hAlign`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ooxml/workbook#configuration-sheets.rows.cells.hAlign) is the attribute set to align text however if using Kendo version 2015.3/newer, this attribute has been deprecated so use [`textAlign`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ooxml/workbook#configuration-sheets.rows.cells.textAlign) instead.

I have also updated the [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/iSeMA/4) to reflect these changes.

Comment: This example not work for me. Can you share full example with me?